# WCF Service ref string param that accepts XML?

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm writing a WCF service that receives events. It's to an agreed standard so I've got to stick to the service definition, and I don't control the data the clients send. Again this is to an agreed standard although the data can vary.

Here's one of the methods on my service:

```
complexType ErrorEvent(int requestId, complexType returnValue, ref string errorInfo)
```

Clients send XML in the errorInfo string that my function will manipulate and return.

The data I get is like this (full SOAP request):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ErrorEvent xmlns="http://blah">
      <requestId>1</requestId>
      <returnValue>
        <returnCode>0</returnCode>
      </returnValue>
      <errorInfo>
        <ErrorMessage>An error message</ErrorMessage>
        <DefaultTask><!-- Complex data --></DefaultTask>
        <Task><!-- Complex data --></Task>
        <Task><!-- Complex data --></Task>
        <Task><!-- Complex data --></Task>
        <ExtraMessage>hello</ExtraMessage>
        <ExtraMessage>world</ExtraMessage>
      </errorInfo>
    </ErrorEvent>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

However, when I try and run this I get this error (edited):

*The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter errorInfo. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. End element 'errorInfo' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'ErrorMessage' from namespace ''.*

So my question is, is there any way I achieve what I want to do without altering the signature of my method? For example adding attributes to my service etc? Or do I need to intercept the message?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Your method signature suggests it is expecting errorInfo to be a string. However, the soap message appears like errorInfo is a composite type. Also why "ref string errorInfo"?

Comment: ref allows him to have in/out parameters. It is the only way to do it in WCF.

Comment: Yes, I want the XML representing the composite type to be returned as a string. It's a ref because it gets returned to the client along with the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to make this work and as @luksan says, it's a misuse by a client to send unescaped XML to a string parameter.

The workaround I adopted was to make a class that implements IClientMessageInspector, IDispatchMessageInspector and IEndpointBehavior to intercept, check and modify any messages that were incorrect.

If I could have changed the interface, another workaround would have been to accept XmlNode[] instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be passed as a string? You know you can also receive XmlElement and XElements in WCF?

Are you generating the SOAP request yourself? Could you use a CDATA section, i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ErrorEvent xmlns="http://blah">
      <requestId>1</requestId>
      <returnValue>
        <returnCode>0</returnCode>
      </returnValue>
      <errorInfo>
        <![CDATA[<ErrorMessage>An error message</ErrorMessage>
        <DefaultTask><!-- Complex data --></DefaultTask>
        <Task><!-- Complex data --></Task>
        <Task><!-- Complex data --></Task>
        <Task><!-- Complex data --></Task>
        <ExtraMessage>hello</ExtraMessage>
        <ExtraMessage>world</ExtraMessage>]]>
      </errorInfo>
    </ErrorEvent>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: I'd like to keep it as a string since the service follows a WSDL that does the same, for another platform. It's possible that client appls may use the WSDL of my service to generate client code too. So yess I'd like to keep it as string.

Comment: On CDATA, I'm not in control of what gets sent unfortunately. Hence, my last resort if no-one knows if I can do this is to intercept the messages and wrap the parameter data in CDATA before it gets to my service.

Comment: It seems that a well-designed SOAP client would automatically escape the `<` as `&lt;` and `>` as `&gt;`, etc., if the WSDL specified that errorInfo was a string parameter, so you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: I agree, but I can't rely on that it seems! :) I think I'm going to have to go down the interception route.

Comment: It seems like they're misusing SOAP/WSDL then, by placing XML tags directly in a string value. Could you post a snippet of the WSDL you're trying to emulate (if there is one)?

Comment: I can't post the WSDL but I agree, it is misuse that causes the issue.